# Silverlight datagrid show or hide controls with combobox selection

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

To make shorter, let's say I have a Datagrid with a combobox a TextBox, and another Combobox. I'd like to show or hide the text or the combobox according to the value selected with the first Combo

```
               <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ComboBox x:Name="cboThenConstOrCol" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM}, Path=cboElseSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="None"/>
                                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Const" />
                                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Col"/>
                                                    </ComboBox>
                                                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElseConst}" Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM}, Path= IsVisibleElseConst}" IsTabStop="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM}, Path=isElseConstTabStop}"></TextBox>
                                                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM}, Path=Fields,Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM}, Path= IsVisibleElseCol}" DisplayMemberPath="FieldName" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

in my Viewmodel i'm taking care of showing or hiding and is working correctly, but the problem is when I make the textbox visible all textbox in all Rows become visible. What I'd like to to is just apply to the row where the combobox selecteditem has been changed. I hope i was clear, otherwise please let me know to add additional info. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather you've got one ViewModel that controls everything. I think you'll run into problems doing this, and while it may seem easier doing things like this at first it definitely isn't when any amount of complexity is introduced. What I'd do is embrace MVVM a bit more and make a ViewModel for the item that each of your Rows represent. This allows each row to maintain it's own state. Here's an example based on what you've provided:

Modified XAML (incomplete):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:VM
        x:Key="vm" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid
    DataContext="{StaticResource vm}"
    x:Name="LayoutRoot"
    Background="White">
    <sdk:DataGrid
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition
                                    Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ComboBox
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=Options}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <TextBox
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Text="Else"
                                Visibility="{Binding TextVisible}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Items is collection containing 'ItemViewModel's. The major change here is that the bindings in the data template now map to properties of 'ItemViewModel'. The exception to this is the ComboBox's ItemSource (which contains your 'None', 'Const' and 'Col' values), which binds to the Main VM.

Main VM:

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> options = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get { return items; } }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Options { get { return options; } }

    public VM()
    {
      options.Add("None");
      options.Add("Const");
      options.Add("Col");      

      //Create some dummy items
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        var item = new ItemViewModel();
        item.Name = i.ToString();
        item.Selected = options[0];
        items.Add(item);
      }
    }

   //INotifyPropertyChanged stuff
```

Item VM:

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string selected;
    private Visibility textVisible;

    public string Selected
    {
      get { return selected; }
      set
      {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
          switch (value.ToLower())
          {
            case "none":
              TextVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
              break;
            case "const":
              TextVisible = Visibility.Visible;
              break;
            case "col":
              TextVisible = Visibility.Visible;
              break;
          }
       }

        selected = value;

      }
    }

    public Visibility TextVisible
    {
      get { return textVisible; }
      set
      {
        textVisible = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("TextVisible");
      }
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged stuff       

}
```

You can see here that when the selected value is changed for this item, some logic is run to determine whether the text should be visible or not.

There's a few things wrong with this but hopefully it gets you on the right path.

Comment: thank you Wdavo. You are absolutely right my code in VM starts getting  really big (almost 2000 lines of code). this grid actually is part of RowDetailTemplate. I will separate my code in several files and VM class. thanks again